# In which Cocoa Touch collection can a nil value be stored?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In which of `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSSet` can I store a `nil` value?

Comment: None of them. What would be the point?

Answer (score 2):

In none.

You can insert instances (it is a shared one) of `NSNull`. But in many cases the need to insert "no value" into a collection is a code smell. The selection of a specific collection should not depend on such facilities, but on how you logically want to access them.

There are collections that can deal with `nil` values, i. e. [`NSPointerArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/). But as mentioned: Usually you do something wrong.